# Swapping hard drive on identical boards

Tags: boot, networking, clone

I have a number of identical PC boards with SSD.
I built an Ubuntu system on the first one and set it up as I needed.
I then used Clonezilla to clone the first SSD and copied this image to the other SSDs. Perfect - works like a charm.

I have now tried to take a SSD from one PC board and use it in one of the other PC boards, but it comes up with an issue while booting ..."waiting for network configuration" and it takes about two minutes to boot. When it has booted there are no network interfaces.

Now I understand that each PC board will have a unique MAC address, and if that was stored somewhere in a config file on the SSD then this may cause a conflict. However if thats the case then how come I'm able to clone the SSD in the first place and don't have this issue with a new cloned SSD.

The OS is Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

Can anyone explain what goes on here ?

Comment: Is it an Ubuntu desktop system or an Ubuntu Server system? The Ubuntu desktop has an automatic network system which is portable, while Ubuntu server 'hard codes' the ethernet settings (I think including the MAC address). I have been able to fix it via the tips at this link:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall#Unmanaged_Wired_Network

Comment: Did you check with ifconfig -a ? That should show all network interfaces, including those without configuration. It is possible that you will find e.g. eth4 or eth3.

Comment: My /etc/network/interfaces file on SSD is

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

After booting the new PC with the SSD with the above network configuration running ifconfig -a shows eth2 and eth3 interfaces but neither are operational.

PS my PC boards have 2 Lan Ports

Comment: Is it Ubuntu Server or a system created from the mini.iso or the server iso file? My  `/etc/network/interfaces` in a desktop system is simpler, only 2 [non-comment] lines: line1: `auto lo`; line2: `iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu Desktop 14.04
and I created the lines in the interfaces file to suit my application. Its as I need it. I cant see why this should affect taking a SSD from one board and placing it in another exact same board !

Answer (score 0):

I have uncovered some additional information. There is a file /etc/udev/reles.d/70-persistent-net.rules. This file has entries in it for each network interface, and those entries include a MAC address. It would appear that on boot the new PC cannot find the MAC Address of the original machine, which is causing the issue. The new PC then adds new entries into this file with the correct MAC addresses for its own hardware. When the system eventually starts (after 2 mins of pondering over the incorrect MAC addresses) the file can be edited and the incorrect entries removed and the new entries renamed eth0 / eth1 etc.

This fixed the startup issue.